# When does android releases objects from memory and how to handle it?

Tags: android

I mean i get crash reports on objects that are null, so my guess is that android releases them maybe when another app needs more memory.

For example an adview becomes null.

Should i check in onResume if an object is null?
if so how to avoid checking for every object?

And i have a static boolean variable which is never destroyed (released), is that because it is static or boolean?

Comment: Take a look at the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: i know that but 1 0f 100 times the adview becomes null

Comment: I don't know what "...every object"  means in the context of your program. I have know idea what kind of objects or how many. The question is just to general--as is has stated.

Comment: Sometimes is shared prefereces other times is the ad view so my current fix is to check if they are null and if they are i reasign them, but im not sure if that is the besti can do

Comment: As far as `SharedPreference` is concerned I personally know of no reason to keep a reference to a `SharedPreference` open throughout the lifecycle of an `Activity` since creating a new `SharedPreference` object when you either need to save to or query the stored data.

Comment: Yeah but it does not matter i mean that is not the reason for it to be released i think i'm  talking about what is known as ghost app, I mean lets talk about adViews then, they are global variables and get destroyed how do i handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android can remove activity from memory, if it hasn't enough memory. 
But if you asking about objects, it can't remove objects, which has strong alive reference, cause of principle of working GC.
And if you go to destroyed activity after, it restores saved objects from Bundle. 
So, you can use singleton, static reference or Bundle to save the reference and keep object alive.
[Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: I think you answer makes sense, so then the problem is that the bundle objects are not being restored? Some resource to learn how objects are restored from bundle?